# Shouldn't this code work UIView class Visibility?

Tags: class, uiview, swift4, xcode9

I have a class that is named Dataview that is connected to an ordinary View in my app and now I'm trying to change the visibility of this view with the class name and alpha and it's not working. So my question is why?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class DataView: UIView {
    var sliderOne = SliderOne()
    var sliderTwo = SliderTwo()
    var sliderThree = SliderThree()

    func visibility(visible: Bool){
        if(visible == true){
           self.alpha = 1.0
        }else if(visible == false){
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }
    }

    func sliderCount(sliderArray:[SliderView]){

    }
}
```

and in my main view I do this:

```
var dataView = DataView() 

override func viewDidAppear(_animated: Bool){
     /*either this*/ dataView.alpha = 0.0 
     /*or this */ dataView.visibility(visible:false)

}
```

I get the result of a view that still is visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import UIKit

class DataView: UIView {
    func setVisibility(_ visible: Bool){
        alpha = visible ? 1 : 0
    }
}

let dataView = DataView()

dataView.setVisibility(true)
print(dataView.alpha) // prints 1.0
dataView.setVisibility(false)
print(dataView.alpha) // prints 0.0
```

Comment: yea it will give the class alpha but if i then assign the class to a view will the view disappear?